# Cloud storage provider with REST API available in China

Tags: javascript, rest, cloud-storage

I work on a web application which uses cloud storage as the primary save mechanism for users. We don't have our own cloud storage service, instead we leverage the REST APIs for Google Drive, Dropbox, etc.

Recently we have noticed an increasingly number of users in China, unfortunately none of the cloud services we currently integrate with are available in China. The alternative forms of saving in the app have limitations which cannot be resolved, and developing our own cloud storage system that functions in China would be a very large engineering undertaking.

As such I have been trying to find a service which we could add that works in China, but have had very little success. Nearly all of the sites are in Chinese, and even with Google Translate I haven't been able to find any company that claims to offer these services. Most have some form of Cloud storage for users, but I haven't been able to find a REST API that would allow us to integrate with them. Any leads someone could provide would be much appreciated.

Requirements:

- HTTP API that can be used from the browser similar to [Dropbox HTTP documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation)
- Can be accessed in the UK ( for development ) and China
- Preferably some documentation in English...
- Ideally free and commonly used in China

Comment: Maybe AWS? An other option would be to use a vpn.

Comment: @csaar AWS was also one thing I considered but based on the question I think it should be a user provided cloud which can be attached to the service for storing user data e.g. by providing access to it via OAuth. Instead of providing access to the storage through the service itself.

Comment: @thex AWS also includes the Amazon Drive api ([api doc](https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/amazon-drive/ad-restful-api.html))

Comment: @csaar ok didn't know that

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented client-side code to work with Chinese storage cloud services (REST API). However this already dates back quite some time. Basically, there is often no English documentation and sadly you have to rely on translation. Also I suggest using a VPN (if that helps) because accessing these services outside from China is often terrible slow. This is also valid for most of the developer docs.

What direction I can point to is [Baidu PCS](http://developer.baidu.com/wiki/index.php?title=%E5%B8%AE%E5%8A%A9%E6%96%87%E6%A1%A3%E9%A6%96%E9%A1%B5/%E4%B8%AA%E4%BA%BA%E4%BA%91%E5%AD%98%E5%82%A8_API) (sadly all links are 404 so [take a look here](http://openapi.baidu.com/wiki/index.php?title=docs/pcs/rest/overview)) which still exist. But as the biggest player this is the first thing I would try. There are probably other providers but the question is how long they will exist because others I have implemented are already gone (e.g. Kanbox).

This is just my experience and it might not fully apply today but maybe it helps.

Update 1: What I also found in a quick search is [Weiyun](https://www.weiyun.com/) which has a [reverse engineered API](https://github.com/Macuyiko/weiyun-api) but yeah that's far from reliable and official supported, but worth a look.

Update 2: Added alternative link for Baidu PCS documentation.

Comment: The Baidu PCS looks promising, I had looked at their site before but hadn't found the PCS service. Unfortunately it looks like nearly every link from that page is currently 404ing for me..

Comment: @nepeo I think I found something that might help you. http://openapi.baidu.com/wiki/index.php?title=docs/pcs/rest/overview Check this link here does the documentation work and also all links are working correctly without 404. I added the link in the answer above.

Comment: @nepeo But the SDK and changelog is quite old so it might don't work. But give it a shot it should be easy to at least establish a basic API connection and see if it works.